# Strong Topology is the strongest topology?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

In his article *Construction of universal bundles. II* (1956), John Milnor defines the strong topology in a join of spaces, but his definition is

> By a **strong topology** in $A_1\circ A_2\circ \dots \circ A_n$ we mean the **strongest topology** such that the coordinate functions
>
> $t_i\colon A_1\circ A_2\circ \dots \circ A_n\longrightarrow [0,1] $  and $a_i\colon t_i^{-1}(0,1]\longrightarrow A_i$
>
> are continuous.

I don't understand the definition of his strong topology. Could anyone explain me it (if possible with an example)? Another question too is: what does he mean with the "*strongest topology*"?

Comment: @Ian apparently "strong" and "weak" mean different things to different people (analysts vs. topologists, according to Munkres p. 78).  Here, the join topology, which Milnor calls the strong topology, is _coarser_ than the quotient topology, which he calls the weak topology.  That is, every set that is open in the join topology is also open in the quotient topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Milnor calls the strong topology on the join 
$$X= X_1 * \cdots * X_n  $$
is called the **join topology** in [Topology and Groupoids](http://gorupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html) (T&G) Section 5.7, and is the **initial topology** with respect to the functions he gives. More formally, this means that a function $f: Z \to X$ is continuous if and and only if its composites with all the "coordinate functions" $t_i,a_i$ are continuous. So this topology is well placed for deciding if functions **to** the join are continuous. This is discussed in Section 5.6 of T&G.

A little care is needed in discussing initial topologies in this case since the functions $a_i$ are **partial functions** on the join $X$, that is they are not defined on all of $X$.

More generally, if $X$ is a set and $f_i: X \to X_i$ is a family of **partial** functions to topological spaces $X_i$, then the initial topology on $X$ with respect to the $f_i$ is the smallest (= coarsest) topology such that all the $f_i$ are continuous.

One of the advantages of this topology is that it is easy to prove associativity of the join, which may not be so if you use an identification (= final) topology, as is quite common.